# Twitter4j throws NoClassDefFoundError in appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

I have download Twitter4j 3.0.1 from http://twitter4j.org. Then I added the following jars in Eclipse appengine 1.7.0.

```
twitter4j-appengine-3.0.1.jar
twitter4j-async-3.0.1.jar
twitter4j-core-3.0.1.jar
twitter4j-examples-3.0.1.jar
twitter4j-media-support-3.0.1.jar
twitter4j-stream-3.0.1.jar
```

code

```
twitter4j.Twitter twitter = new twitter4j.TwitterFactory().getInstance();
twitter.setOAuthConsumer("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxxxxxxx");
twitter4j.auth.RequestToken requestToken  = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken();
```

It successfully compiling but got the below error while running.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: twitter4j/Twitter.
```

But the same code working fine If i create a new java console project instead of appengine.

Comment: Have you found the fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

Now Twitter4j released new versions with following features,

Twitter4J is featuring: 
✔ 100% Pure Java - works on any Java Platform version 5 or later
✔ Android platform and Google App Engine ready
✔ Zero dependency : No additional jars required
✔ Built-in OAuth support
✔ Out-of-the-box gzip support
✔ 100% Twitter API 1.1 compatible

Download 3.0.3 its supporting Appengine. http://twitter4j.org/en/ .Thanks.